# Xamarin dependent project failed to build

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, xamarin-live-player

I got this error when try to start Android solution in Xamarin Live Player on VS2017.

"Dependent project xx.csproj failed to build, using old version"

Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: if you build just the failed project, what does it say?

Comment: no errors on build

Comment: are you actually looking at the verbose build output?

Comment: yes, the build complete successfull

Comment: if the dependent project builds, then try re-building the parent project.  You may also want to clean it first, or manually delete the bin and obj folders

Comment: I just installed Xamarin Live Player **16 hours ago** and have the same issue. The first time I used Xamarin Live for the project it worked, but since then it always fails saying "Dependent project xx failed to build" and it uses the old version instead. My changes to project were only one character in the welcome string of the template MainPage.

Comment: yes me too. I create a new project and only changed the "hello xamarin" string and have the same problem again.

Comment: maybe it's my impression but I think that message is show for each type of error. I solved it simply ricreate the project and test every time I change some code. So the error is another one and not what the message write, check your code.

Comment: Now tracking this here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1787 with a workaround for today. Will post an update to app soon